# Kolmogorov-Smirnov test fails to recognize a normally distributed sample

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, normality-assumption, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I created a sample with 10000 normally distributed numbers. Subsequently, I used the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to check if they are indeed normally distributed, and it turned out that they are not. How is this possible?

Below is my code.

```
data <- rnorm(n=10000, 5, 2)
ks.test(data, "pnorm")
```

And this is the answer:

Exact one-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  data
D = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

Comment: Hint: What distribution is the `rnorm` in your code drawing from? What distribution is `pnorm` defining?

Comment: If you test at a level of 5%, as you know, 5% of the samples will be rejected under the null.

Comment: @AlexJ `rnorm` generates 1000 normally distributed numbers. Then, I am trying to see if they follow the normal distribution (`pnorm`). Therefore, the null hypothesis should not be rejected.

Comment: @utobi , I filled in the answer provided by R.

Comment: You should make a habit of using `set.seed()` to make the random values reproducible. But to the point: If not specified, `ks.test` will test against a standard normal. So you should use `ks.test(data, "pnorm", 5, 2)`. But please remember that the KS-test assumes the parameters to be known a priori and not estimated from the data. Also pay close attention to what utobi said. Finally, no normality test can confirm that your sample is normally distributed. Non-significance does not mean "normally distributed".

Comment: @COOLSerdash Oh! You're right. I thought it automatically took into account the mean and standard deviation. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As highlighted in the comments ([Alex J](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/369002/alex-j) and   [COOLSerdash](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/21054/coolserdash)), there are two issues here. First, the model used under the KS test is different from the true model that generated the data. The correct way would be either

```
> set.seed(12)
> set.seed(30823)
> data <- rnorm(n=10000, 5, 2)
> ks.test(data, "pnorm", mean=5, sd=2)

    Asymptotic one-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  data
D = 0.0044899, p-value = 0.9877
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

or

```
> data1 <- rnorm(n=10000)
> ks.test(data1, "pnorm")

    Asymptotic one-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  data1
D = 0.01079, p-value = 0.1947
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Second (a minor issue), the test if used at level 0.05 has still (approximately) 5% of a chance to reject the null even if the null is true.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The issue has been resolved.